# Passing variable to javascript block from asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, literals

I have a grid view in which one header template "select all" is there which on checked will select all the check box in grid view rows.

I have a pagesize dropdown which on selecting will open that number of gridview rows.  Initially it is set to 10.

Initially when the gridview is loaded and when I do select all it selects the 10 checkboxes, later when I change the page size to 50 and do select all, still it selects only 10 records. However, it should select all 50 records, which is not happening.

I am passing the array variable to the literal control on click of select all checkboxes which is getting the number of rows as the number in the gridview, but the function in JavaScript still retains the same old value of 10 rows so it selects 10 records.

My code:

```
protected void gvDeviceList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e){
    try {
        //repopulate the already ticked checkboxes
        RePopulateCheckboxes(gvDeviceList);

        if (gvDeviceList.Rows.Count > 0) {
            CheckBox cbHeader = (CheckBox)(gvDeviceList.HeaderRow.FindControl("chbOptions"));
            cbHeader.Attributes["onclick"] = "ChangeAllCheckBoxStates(this.checked);";

            //ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("CheckBoxIDs", String.Concat("'", cbHeader.ClientID, "'"));
            //Add the CheckBox's ID to the client-side CheckBoxIDs array
            List<String> ArrayValues = new List<String>();
            ArrayValues.Add(String.Concat("'", cbHeader.ClientID, "'"));

            foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvDeviceList.Rows) {
                //Get a programmatic reference to the CheckBox control
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)(gvr.FindControl("chbAction"));

                //Add the CheckBox's ID to the client-side CheckBoxIDs array
                //ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("CheckBoxIDs", String.Concat("'", cb.ClientID, "'"));
                ArrayValues.Add(String.Concat("'", cb.ClientID, "'"));
            }


            //Output the array to the Literal control (CheckBoxIDsArray)
            CheckBoxIDsArray.Text = "<script type='text/javascript'>" + "\r\n" +
                                    "" + "\r\n" +
                                    String.Concat("var CheckBoxIDs = new Array(", String.Join(",", ArrayValues.ToArray()), ");") + "\r\n" +
                                    "" + "\r\n" +
                                    "</script>";
        }
```

The Literal control is:

```
<asp:Literal ID="CheckBoxIDsArray" runat="server" Visible="True"></asp:Literal>
```

And my JavaScript code is:

```
function ChangeAllCheckBoxStates(checkState) {
    // Toggles through all of the checkboxes defined in the CheckBoxIDs array
    // and updates their value to the checkState input parameter
    if (CheckBoxIDs != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < CheckBoxIDs.length; i++)
        ChangeCheckBoxState(CheckBoxIDs[i], checkState);
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The code you've posted looks like it should work - is there anything else going on - AJAX Update panels etc?

Comment: Yes ajax update panels are there

Comment: Is the gridview and literal inside the same panel?